# Тире при наличии вводного предложения и связки ЭТО между подлежащим и сказуемым

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Необходимо ли тире перед связкой ЭТО при наличии вводной конструкции, например:

А правда, *говорит он*, (—) это сокровище.

Человек, *как замечает писатель*, (—) это создание своенравное.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста,  контекст для первого предложения.

Comment: "Говорит он" — указание на источник. То есть можно бы оформить как: "А правда, — говорит он, — это сокровище". Но автор выбрал вариант без прямой речи.

Comment: Да, можно считать "говорит он" вводными словами.  Но о чем здесь вообще  разговор, о каком сокровище?  Может,  это моралисты правду называют сокровищем (тоже любопытное мнение), а может  кто-то реальные сокровища ищет.  Это цитата или что это? Откуда вообще взят текст, откройте нам тайну. Или приведите пару предложений из контекста.

Comment: Это цитата из авторского текста (философского), еще не выпущенного, он сейчас на корректуре. Имеется в виду: "Правда — это сокровище".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я дам **полный ответ** по этой теме, чтобы заданный вопрос был понятен участникам, при этом ставлю плюс и автору вопроса, и отвечающему.

**ОТВЕТ**

*А правда, **говорит он**, — это сокровище.*

*Человек, **как замечает писатель**, — это создание своенравное.*

**Пояснение**

1. Да, тире ставится **перед словом-связкой ЭТО,** стоящим перед сказуемым (при этом надо точно знать, что это действительно сказуемое в простом предложении).

Вводная конструкция **обособляется запятыми** с двух сторон и постановке тире не препятствует.

2. Но при отсутствии связки ЭТО и наличии вводной конструкции **тире не ставится**: *Дубава, **кажется**, друг Корчагина. Риск, **как известно**, дело благородное.*

[§ 5. Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым. Пункт 1. Примечание (4)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92)

Answer (score 2):

Тире в данных случаях необходимо.
Тире *всегда* ставится перед указательными словами *это*, *вот*, *значит*, входящими в состав сказуемого.

Comment: Вам понятна грамматика первого предложения?  Простое, сложное, осложненное? Если простое, то где подлежащее и сказуемое?

Comment: @Sharon я думаю, что перед нами простое осложнённое предложение: подлежащее - "правда", сказуемое - "это сокровище", вводная конструкция - "говорит он".

Comment: Странная семантика у предложения. Похоже на цитату, но поисковики не находят.  Но если это действительно так, то тире ставится перед ЭТО. Вводная конструкция постановке тире не препятствует.